# How to compare items form two different dynamic arrays in Ruby/rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, iteration

I have two models Clients and Teammates.

Clients has projects.

Each Teammate has his own `teammate_project` which are:

> select(:client_project, current_user.clients.pluck(:project)

I need to display in Client's view which teammates belongs to particular Client through projects. But without additional DB column in Clients/Teammates table.

For now I have:

```
class FrontPagesController < ApplicationController
  def front
    if signed_in?
      mess {current_user}
      @clients.each do |client|
        client_teammates = current_user.teammates.where(client_project: client.project)
        @client_teammates = client_teammates.pluck(:secondname)
      end
    end
  end

  private

    def mess
      #multiple
        @accounts = yield.accounts.all
        @teammates = yield.teammates.all
        @clients = yield.clients.all
        @perks = yield.perks.all
      #single 
        @account = yield.accounts.build 
        @teammate = yield.teammates.build
        @client = yield.clients.build
        @perk = yield.perks.build
    end
end
```

And view:

```
- @client_teammates.each do |c_t|
  %ul
    %li - #{c_t}
```

But it doesn't work properly. It takes some teammates but they aren't correct

Need your help

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly what you want, but one your mistake is obvious.

You should change your code to:

```
def front
  if signed_in?
    mess {current_user}
    @clients_teammates = []
    @clients.each do |client|
      client_teammates = current_user.teammates.where(client_project: client.project)
      @clients_teammates << client_teammates.pluck(:secondname)
    end
  end
end
```

And you can improve your code this way:

```
def front
  if signed_in?
    mess {current_user}
    @clients_teammates = current_user.teammates.where(client_project_id: @clients.pluck(:project_id))
    # if @clients is an Array (if you use Rails3)
    # @clients_teammates = current_user.teammates.where(client_project_id: @clients.map(&:project_id))  
  end
end
```

Or if you are very cool programmer, you can do it somehow like:

```
def front
  if signed_in?
    mess {current_user}
    @clients_teammates = current_user.teammates.joins("JOIN projects ON teammates.client_project_id = projects.id").joints("JOIN clients ON projects.id = clients.project_id").where("clients.user_id = ?", current_user.id)  
  end
end
```